# Unsupported Media Type: upload files

Tags: angular, file-upload, jax-rs

my document-upload.service.ts

```
private uploadFile(file: File) {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
        return this.http.post(`${this.uploadUrl}`, formData, {headers: headers, responseType: 'text' });
    }
```

my RestResourceFileUpload.java

```
    @Path("/fileupload")
public class RestResourceFileUpload
{
    @Inject
    private FileUploadDomainService fileUploadDomainService;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response fileUpload(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition formContent) throws SGDevException, IOException
    {}
```

When i call my rest service i get

> [WARNING ] javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

:( 
Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: It's because i use @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition formContent, without this parameter, all it's ok but i need FormDataContentDisposition :/

Comment: You don't need to set the headers for content-type. FormData already does this automatically

Answer (score 1):

Add your file as a Blob and dont set the Content-Type in the Http-Headers:

```
  const params = new HttpParams().set('value', value);
const url = `${this.serviceResource}/runTest`;

const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('test', new Blob([JSON.stringify(test)], {
  type: "application/json"
}));
fd.append('placeholders', new Blob([JSON.stringify(placeholders)], {
  type: "application/json"
}));

return this.http.post<Test>(url, fd, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: token
    //   'Content-Type': undefined,  -> FormData generrates Content Type automatically
  }),
  params
});
```

Spring Part:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/runTest", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public Test runTest(
    @RequestParam("value") String value,
    @RequestPart("test") Test test,
    @RequestPart("placeholders") ArrayList< Placeholder> placeholders,
```

this is automatically generated:

[image]

and through adding it as a BLOB the files get their own Content Type:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I could find concerning multipart with angular set Content-Type to undefined, why are you providing that ?(Copied from Marsup on https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/460 )
I had both of these problems:
 "Invalid multipart payload format" and 
"Unsupported Media Type".
first solved by using  Content-Type to undefined and 
second by using FormData and append to it.
and because you use FromData, changing Content-Type to undefined may help.
That is the idea that came to my mind :) wish it works for you too !